# Mongoose populate with array of objects not working

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a exam mongoose schema and question schema

exam schema is shown as followed

```
const fields = {
  name : {  type : String,  required : true },
  pages: [{
      name: String,
      description: String,
      questions: [{
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "question",required: true,  
        }
      ],
    },
  ],
  createdBy: { type: String,  required: true, },
};
```

question schema is shown as followed

```
const fields = {
  name : {  type : String,  required : true },
  answer: {  type : String,  required : true }
};
```

then I want to get the full example of the exam instance with the code

```
await collection.findById(id).populate("pages.questions")
```

but the result doesn't show me the question in detail, anything wrong with it?

Comment: can you show how you created the model for both the schemes?